# objc_getAssociatedObject and Runtime attributes

Tags: swift, extension-methods, xib, swift5

I have the following extension which was used to automatically save/retrieve runtime attributes unique to a UIImageView:

```
import UIKit

var imgAttributeKey:String? = nil

extension UIImageView {
    
    var imgAttribute: String? {
        get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &imgAttributeKey) as? String }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imgAttributeKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) }
    }
    
}
```

[image]

This was working fine but after trying the code again recently, the getters were always returning nil. Did something change in Swift 5 version that could be breaking this implementation? Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the setter and check if this is being called by system during XIB decoding process?

Comment: No, the setter is not being called.

Comment: Can you try adding `@objc` in front of this declaration? `@objc var imgAttribute: String?`

Comment: I get a 'objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes' error.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I'm running iOS 14.5 iPhone X/Xcode 12.5

Comment: I don't get any error in a Swift Playground (Swift 5.3) See this https://imgur.com/2KSRhQG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Tarun Tyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6458001/tarun-tyagi) for pointing out the correct fix.

**@objc** needs to be added to the property reference in the extension. Incorrectly marking the outside property results in a *objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes* error.

Working code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

var imgAttributeKey:String? = nil

extension UIImageView {
    
    @objc var imgAttribute: String? {
        get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &imgAttributeKey) as? String }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imgAttributeKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) }
    }
    
}
```

The reason why this was needed it that this project was originally written in Swift 3 but starting from Swift 4, an explicit annotation @objc for  dynamic Objective-C features (such as User Defined Runtime Attributes) is required.